What am I doing wrong to get this error for Google Vision API
I have been getting a "Error opening File: gs://{gs-bucket-path}/{gs bucket folder path} - In VS code
I have tried it in Postman and receive "Error opening file: gs://{gs-bucket-path}/{gs bucket folder path} permission denied.
I have a Service Account created under the project for this OCR API project, I downloaded the JSON and ensure in PowerShell that the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL key/path is pointing correctly to my JSON file that I downloaded. I have set API keys and tried OAuth 2.0 credentials.
I am pretty new to doing APIs and having to deal with CRUD and JSON but have learned an ok amount of terminology with messing up so much.
I have set permissions under my account in the organization as Storage Object Owner
Project IAM Admin
Project Mover
Storage Admin
Storage Folder Admin
Storage Object Admin
Storage Object Creator
Storage Object Viewer
Have also set the Service Account permissions under the Project as Storage Object Creator, Storage Object Viewer, & Storage Object User Removed it as Owner as I read on another post that its not a good idea.
I'm confused.
Here is my code from postman and the error i am receiving
POST   https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/files:asyncBatchAnnotate?key={{key}} this is where I'm calling.
    {
  "requests": [
    {
      "inputConfig": {
        "gcsSource": {
          "uri": "gs://My-Path-To-My-GsBucket/My-Path-To-Folder&File.pdf"
        },
        "mimeType": "application/pdf"
        
      },
      "outputConfig": {
        "gcsDestination": {
          "uri": "gs://My-Path-To-Output-Folder/"
        },
        "batchSize": 1
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
          
        }
        
      ]
      
    }

  ]
  
}

the response i get is "error":{
"code":403
"message": error opening file { my path}
"status": Permission_denied

Have you gone through the suggestions here

Yes. I ensured my path doesn't end with a "", mine ends with ".pdf" @Sathi Aiswarya

Your question lacks detail for us to help. Please provide a minimal-repro of your issue. This should show (not describe) the commands/code that you're running. gs://{bucket}/{object} represents a proprietary URI used by Cloud Storage that is only usable by Google's client libraries. IIUC Postman does not include a Cloud Storage client and so won't be able to access GCS URIs and you'll need to use the https://storage.cloud.google.com/{bucket}/{object} URI.

Sure thing, I provided the info in my edit. Also I forked the Vision API from a workspace recommended in a Postman Video about the Vision API, just different annotate methods. @DazWilkin

Ok, your POST body works for me but you don't show the headers. You will need to include an Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN} header to authenticate your request. Are you doing this?

I am not doing that currently, I am going to do that and will report back. TY @DazWilkin

The easiest way is if you have gcloud installed, you can get a token (TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token) and then --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}". You'll also want to --header "X-Goog-User-Project: ${PROJECT}"

So i found a Postman video on setting up Google OAuth from the actual google cloud console, followed that guide, found out i had some information in the Auth URL wrong in the OAuth 2.0 set up on postman along with a Client Authentication was wrong. Fixed & ran that. Received a token, used as bearer and no error anymore. Onto the next step! TY so much for everyone's help.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Seems the service account does not have permission to access the file, so you need to set up proper permissions to use the PDF API (or any other API involving this file). See this documentation for details:
Try adding the scope googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform (View and manage your data across Google Cloud Platform services). For more information check this Cloud Storage OAuth 2.0 scopes

Most of the operations you perform in Cloud Storage must be authenticated. The only exceptions are operations on resources that allow anonymous access.
Authorization is the process of determining what permissions an authenticated identity has on a set of specified resources. OAuth 2.0 uses scopes to determine if an authenticated identity is authorized. Applications use a credential (obtained from a user-centric or server-centric authentication flow) together with one or more scopes to request an access token from a Google authorization server to access protected resources.

Also as stated here This error (403) indicates that the user was not authorized by Google Cloud Storage to make the request.

A common source of this error is that the bucket permissions (bucket ACL) are not set properly to allow your app access. See Google Cloud Storage Authentication for information on setting up access.

If you are still facing the issue consider contacting Google Cloud Support to further investigate the problem.

I have set the permissions for the service account already and still received the error of Permission Denied, i have the above scope + https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision & https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write . I am going to attempt the Bearer token method and if that doesn't worth I'll give the OAuth 2.0 another go. Thank you for your response @Sathi Aiswarya
